# Scroll down until invisible element becomes visible using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scroll down on a page until a certain criteria is met.
The criteria is that the date of the latest visible soccer match is earlier than the reference date.
I wrote the following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


if __name__ == '__main__':
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get('https://hdmatches.com/category/premier-league/')
   matches = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="td-outer-wrap"]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]')
   last_date = \
       matches.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="td_module_10 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack"]')[
       -1].find_element_by_class_name('item-details').find_element_by_class_name(
       'td-module-meta-info').find_element_by_class_name('td-post-date').text
   last_date = datetime.strptime(last_date, '%B %d, %Y').date()
   start_season = datetime.strptime('2017-8-11', '%Y-%m-%d').date()

   while last_date > start_season:
      load_more = matches.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="td-load-more-wrap td-load-more-infinite-wrap"]')
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", load_more)
      matches = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="td-outer-wrap"]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]')
      last_date = \
          matches.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="td_module_10 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack"]')[
          -1].find_element_by_class_name('item-details').find_element_by_class_name(
          'td-module-meta-info').find_element_by_class_name('td-post-date').text
      last_date = datetime.strptime(last_date, '%B %d, %Y').date()
```

My script doesn't work sofar (nothing happens) and I think it because of the below element:

[image]

While scrolling down, this element is two times visible when the page is loading. Afterwards, the following element is the one that loads the page:

[image]

Please advice/help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to the bottom of the page, click the Load More button and repeat until you hit your date.  It appears the game dates don't go that far back and your start season date wasn't hit, so I changed it to a year later and it worked.  I, also, used javascript to click the Load More button because there was something else blocking it using webdriver.  Here are the code changes:

```
start_season = datetime.strptime('2018-8-11', '%Y-%m-%d').date()

   while last_date > start_season:
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
      load_more = matches.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="td-load-more-wrap td-load-more-infinite-wrap"]')
      driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", load_more)
      matches = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="td-outer-wrap"]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]')
      last_date = \
          matches.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="td_module_10 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack"]')[
          -1].find_element_by_class_name('item-details').find_element_by_class_name(
          'td-module-meta-info').find_element_by_class_name('td-post-date').text
      last_date = datetime.strptime(last_date, '%B %d, %Y').date()
```